# How to parse the jenkins log at the postbuild and display text?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

In my script I have added "TestResult => Test description => Pass" and "TestResult => Test Description => Fail" as per the need.
As part of the post build , the lines start with TestResult and contains => should be displayed. I added post build groovy script but the result is not showing post build output.

Below is my sample execute shell

[image]

below is my post build groovy script
[image]

But in the result ,I am not seeing groovy file post build output at all

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bit tricky to find, but if you check out the last example in the [Official Documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy-postbuild/) of the Groovy Post Build plugin you will find it:

> Example 10 (thanks to Frank Merrow).
> Trivial, but hard to find the first time: Write a line to the job's Console > Output:
>
> `manager.listener.logger.println("I want to see this line in my job's output");`

So just change your `println` statements to `manager.listener.logger.println`:

```groovy
def result = ...
manager.listener.logger.println(result.toString());
manager.listener.logger.println("Sample Groovy Line");
```